# Whats the difference for DNS servers if there is the www subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, ip, vps

I've got a VPS, and a domain. The domain was associated with a host/hosting service by a company (provided LAMP) before, when i had enough from them, so i changed the DNS records to my VPS ip adress on the domain admin page of the company.

All works fine now, except if i use the adress with the www subdomain.
I added 3 records:

```
<domainname>.<country> VPS-ip
*.<domainname>.<country> VPS-ip
www.<domainname>.<country> VPS-ip
```

The first two gets resolved with the right adress, but last one not.
Does the www resolved somehow else? 
Or does it take some time to cascade it top the top?

Comment: Wouldn't *.domainname.country take care of the www entry already?

Comment: @Aaron I don't think that statement should take the form of a question :-)

Comment: If you told us your actual domain name, we could simply make a couple DNS requests and probably tell you what your problem is.  Is the anonymization really necessary?

Comment: It was the TTL/DNS cacheing what i was missing. I gave answer for Mathias because he wrote it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your last question: "Or does it take some time to cascade it top the top?"

Yes (if I've understood your question correctly), if the `www` subdomain previously existed, you'd have to wait for the record to propagate between the nameservers as well for TTL to expire. Since no other DNS servers could possibly cache **ALL** records matching `*.domain.tld`, that one is easier to verify.

For example I doubt `mathias-is-an-even-more-beautiful-man.domain.tld` has ever been queried, and thus never cached (= no wait for TTL to expire). The `www` subdomain is more likely to have been queried and cached recently :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your wildcard-entry (*) will match every single request made.

Try looking up pauska-is-a-beautiful-man.domain.tld, you'll be surprised :)

Comment: I was under the impression that a wildcard would only be used if there was not an explicit record for a requested name.

Comment: Ah, true. Well, the host should resolve either way.

Comment: Ye i do know that. Still with the www prefix its resolved for the "old" ip. Is there maybe an upper level witch stores it cached, and need some time to get the new adress?

Comment: @Zoredache That is true, but in the sense that the explicit `www` record is needless when it has the same value as any other 1.-level subdomain, pauska is right

Comment: Yes, DNS records are cached according to the TTL setting on either the zone or per record. Have you tried using nslookup directly against the nameserver where your domain is hosted?